# Retain Config file values in Memory so that it can be used through out the application

Tags: c#, .net, windows-services

I have windows service which invokes some wcf services at regular intervals, like every 5 mins.

So every 5 mins when the code reaches the place where i need to invoke WCF service, i need to read some values from config. And i have 4 different operations on a WCF service which are invoked from the windows service every 5 mins and all 4 of them are trying to read different keys from config file.

What i am trying to do is, read all this configs at the service start and retain them in memory so that i can use it whenever required.

And i am planning to do this :-

1. Create a static class with required no. of static variables
2. Call a method in static class from the OnStart() method to set the above variables
3. And use the static fields wherever required.

Is the approach correct?

thanks
Pradeep

Comment: There are dozens of ways of doing this. If your question is simply "will this work?", then the answer is yes. But I'm always a bit suspicious of using "static" as a lazy man's approach to disseminating data to multiple parts of a program. Typically, with a tiny bit of extra work, you can create a solution based on instantiating a non-static object and copying references to this object around to the places that need it, and this solution will be more flexible and extendable when future changes are needed.

Comment: If you store your config values locally then just use the provided function Settings.Default.<YourParam> rather then creating another static class

Answer (score 0):

I believe your way is correct. But what I think to store config values in db and read from service init into static properties.So if any frequent change in config, you can easily change db values  without doing any deployment/config change.